# 2-Dimensional Array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

We are given an assignment regarding 2-D array which states:
Given a rectangular 2-d  `char grid [row] [col]`  and a  `char`  to look for, find the smallest rectangle that contains all the occurrences of that char and returns its area. If there is only a single occurrence of the char, then the rectangle to enclose it is 1x1 and the area is 1. If the character does not appear, return an area of 0.
 Here is the link to the problem and an example: http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs108/handouts081/03HW1CodeCamp.pdf (page 2) but we have to use  `int charArea (char[][] grid, char ch)`  instead of  `int charArea (char ch)`  
Please help me come up with an algorithm. I am new in Java and I'm having a hard time thinking of a pseudocode/code. All I know is

```
import java.util.*;

public class Area {

    public static int charArea (char[][] grid, char ch) {
        for (int i=0; i<3; i++) { //row
            for (int j=0; j<4; j++) { //column
            // What now, please?                        
            }
        }
        return answer;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[][] grid = {
                {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'},
                {'a', ' ', 'c', 'd'},
                {'x', 'b', 'c', 'a'}
        };
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a character to look for: ");
        String temp = input.nextLine();
        char ch = temp.charAt(0);
        System.out.print(charArea(grid, ch));
    }

}
```

Just please help me design an algorithm/pseudocode (or code, if you don't mind haha). Thank you so much!

Comment: What's the question then? "*Design the complete algorithm*"?

Comment: You just need to check to see if the character at that location is the character you are looking for... I think you should be figuring out how to do that seeing as how this is HOMEwork not STACKOVERFLOWwork

Comment: The whole point of questions like this is to challenge you when you first start.  Sit down, pen and paper, turn your computer off, logically think what steps you would take to solve the problem step by step on paper.  Then write out some pseudo code.  Doing this will put you in a much better position.

Comment: Community doesn't do homework assignments for people. Provide what have you tried or how you think the solution might be and community will help you with that basis.

Answer (score 3):

You need to find a bounding box.

Imagine it like this:

You have 2 vertical and 2 horizontal rulers, one at each side of the matrix (up, down, left and right).

Take the left vertical ruler and move it right until you hit the letter you are looking for.
Take the right vertical ruler and move it left until you hit the letter you are looking for.
Take the upper horizontal ruler and move it down until you hit the letter you are looking for.
Take the lower horizontal ruler and move it upuntil you hit the letter you are looking for.

When you are done, the 4 rulers will form a minimal bounding box.
All that is left for you is a case when there is no such char in your array (hint: "right" ruler will be left from the "left" ruler).

This is the most basic approach, maybe not optimal, but fairly understandable. :D

Answer (score 1):

Since this is an assignment, I'll give you the basic idea on which you might come up with `your own solution`: a rectangle can be defined in function of its four corners. You could find such corners. Note that the farthest-to-the-right occurrence of `ch`, the farthest-to-the-left, the top one and the bottom one would help, but they are not necessarily the corners! For instance, the top left corner would be the `(x,y)`, where `x` is the row of the left-most occurrence of `ch`, and `y` would be the column of the top one.

With the coordinates of the four corners, you can define the smallest rectangle containing all occurrences of `ch` in the matrix.

Comment: I would modify this slightly, since you are saying its four corners then telling them to search for the extreme occurances.  The occurances themselves won't be the corners but the coordinates shared amoungst them will be.

Comment: Rectangles are fully defined by two corners ;) You do not need four.

Comment: Based in the sample text, the rectangle needs 2 corners, not four.

Comment: Well, you still can define based on four of its corners. I never said you *had* to. I just thought the explanation would be easier to follow this way.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of ways to think about the problem.

1. How would you solve this problem with pencil and paper?  Analyze the steps you went through as you solved the problem by hand, and think how you would turn that into logical steps, say to explain to a child how to find the rectangle.
2. Essentially, if you examine how you "bound" something in, you'll need to look for the characters at the furthest extremes of the rectangle, i.e., the corners.  Find the left-most, upper-most, right-most, and bottom-most locations and you have defined a rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

Divide your problem. What do you need to do?

1.) You need to detect the upper left corner
2.) You need to detect the lower right corner
3.) Everything in between is your rectangle

Now, the nest for-loops in `charArea` already loop through the array form the top left to the bottom right. 
You'll have to detect 2-4 occurences of that specific char. You need, depending on the situation, either 2 chars to fully define a corner of your rect, or just one.

So when you have the top-left und bottom-right corner of the rect, calculating how big it is should not be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

The question is: How do you use the array from your code. Well, you should start by looking for variable definition, specifically for variables within a Class. You may start reading http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html. It's called Field, and that's what you are using for your grid declaration...

Answer (score 0):

what i would do is take the char from the parameter and find the first occurrence of it, and store it in an  2-d array of ints to hold a set a coordinates. Then maybe work backwards and start at the end of your 2-d array and find the last occurrence, because then you know the range they can be in.

---

```
public static int charArea (char[][] grid, char ch) {
    int[] first = new int[2];
    int[] last = new int[2];
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++) { //row
        for (int j=0; j<4; j++) { //column
               //checks to see if it is the char we need
               if(grid[i][j].equals(ch) && (first[0] != null && first[1] != null)){
                  first[0] = i;
                  first[1] = j;
               }
        }
    }

    for (int i=3; i>0; i--) { //row
        for (int j=4; j>4; j--) { //column
           //checks to see if it is the char we need
               if(grid[i][j].equals(ch) && (first[0] != null && first[1] != null)){
                  last[0] = i;
                  last[1] = j;
               }                    
        }
    }

    answer = ((Math.max(first[0],last[0]) - Math.min(first[0],last[0])) *(Math.max(first[1],last[1]) - Math.min(fist[1],last[1]));

    return answer;
}
```

Comment: You should **not** give the answer when the question is homework.